# Bash command won't execute in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute a Bash command from inside of a Jupyter Notebook that writes a random number to some files.  The command I'd like to issue is

```
echo $(( RANDOM )) &> {output_files[i]}
```

where `output_files` is a Python list of output filenames.  I can't figure out how to put the Python variable `output_files[i]` into a Bash command successfully, so instead I create the entire command as a string and try to execute that through the Notebook:

```
# Create a list of 5 filenames
output_files = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'random-%s.txt' % i) for i in range (5)]

# Write random number to each file
for i in range (5):
    command = "echo $(( RANDOM )) &> " + output_files[i]
    print(command)
    !{command}
```

When I try this, the files `./random-0.txt` etc. are created, but no number is written to them - they are empty.  When I run the created commands directly in the terminal, though, it works exactly as expected.  The files are created and contain a single random number each.  The `print(command)` line produces

```
echo $(( RANDOM )) &> /filepath/random-0.txt
0
echo $(( RANDOM )) &> /filepath/random-1.txt
echo $(( RANDOM )) &> /filepath/random-2.txt
echo $(( RANDOM )) &> /filepath/random-3.txt
echo $(( RANDOM )) &> /filepath/random-4.txt
```

Web searches for this problem give hits for several similar questions on Stack Overflow as well as blogs, but the result of all of them is either "Bash commands don't exist on Windows" or "You can use '!' to execute Bash commands in Jupyter Notebooks!" with no further information about how it works so that I could debug an issue like this.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Why not do the whole thing in Python itself>

Comment: As an aside, the `&>` redirection is not adding anything useful over plain `>` and in fact, in the unlikely even that you actually get an error message,. you probably *don't* want it to overwrite your output file.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do the whole thing in `python` itself? Use the `random` module the `randint()` function to generate your numbers. Define a range of your choice and include it within the `(..)`

```
import os
import random
output_files = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'random-%s.txt' % i) for i in range (5)]
for of in output_files:
    with open(of, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(random.randint(99,1000)))
```

Comment: I'm comparing two methods, one of which is Bash-based, and I need to keep as much the same as possible.  But it doesn't matter why, the question as asked is well-defined, with a well-defined answer.  If you can answer it as asked, please do.

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow,

As far as I can tell, your issue does not arise form the bash command execution with `!` but rather from the fact that you do not "replace" `output_files[i]` by its actual content.
When you run the loop

```
# Write random number to each file
for i in range (5):
    command = "echo $(( RANDOM )) &> {output_files[i]}"
```

in each iteration, `command` will be the literal string `"echo $(( RANDOM )) &> {output_files[i]}"`. As you did in your first line, you should use string substitution to replace a placeholder with the content of `output_files[i]`:

```
# Write random number to each file
for i in range (5):
    command = ("echo $(( RANDOM )) &> {%s}"%output_files[i])
```

To debug such an issue, it is usually a good start to inspect the value of the variable in question. The easiest way of doing so is by adding `print (x)` lines where `x` is the variable whose content you want to inspect.

Comment: The error you point out was only an error in how I typed the question, it wasn't in the code.  I was correcting it while you were typing your answer, I think.  `print()` does confirm that `command` is being created exactly as the string(s) I want.  I tried your suggestion for constructing `command`, and the result is the same: the five files `random-i.txt` are created, but they do not contain numbers.

Comment: Can you maybe update the question with the content of `command` for each of the loop bodys? Just to be sure.

Comment: Nevermind, I think the answer by @Inian is a better way to approach this.

Comment: I've edited the question with this info.  Also, no, it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

In reaction to one of the answers here, let me show how to do this with `subprocess.check_call()`.

If you want to use a shell redirection in `subprocess`, you have to have a shell:

```
for i in range(5):
    subprocess.check_call('echo "$RANDOM" >random-{}.txt'.format(i), shell=True)
```

You could superficially try to get rid of the `shell=True` ... but then `echo` and `$RANDOM` are shell features, too.

A pure-Bash solution would be

```
!for i in {0..4}; do printf "%s\n" "$RANDOM" >random-"$i".txt; done
```

(As an aside, the numeric context in `$((RANDOM))` is not wrong, but entirely superfluous.)

You can interpolate a Python expression into the `!` command line with `{...}`. The following also works, for example:

```
!{';'.join(['echo $RANDOM >random-{}.txt'.format(i) for i in range(5)])}
```

In iPython I can produce the results I expect with the construct you tried:

```
in [15]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     c='echo $RANDOM >random-{}.txt'.format(i)
    ...:     !{c}
    ...:

in [16]: !tail random-*.txt
==> random-0.txt <==
15637

==> random-1.txt <==
32475
```

If Jupyter is using the iPython kernel, I'm thinking this ought to work for you, too.

Notice also how I used plain old `>` redirection rather than `&>` - there really *really **really*** is no sane reason to want error messages to be redirected to the files; and if a file can't be created, you have absolutely no idea what failed or why, or even *that* it failed. (I suspect this is really the reason for your problems, actually. Permission denied? Disk full? We can't know.)

I would suggest you use Python to perform this simple task, though. Running a subprocess to perform something which is relatively easy in Python itself is inefficient and clumsy as well as somewhat brittle.

Comment: Nice solutions. I have had success with the second two commands, however the first command raises a ```FileNotFoundError``` for me.

Comment: Oh I left old code into the answer, sorry about that; hopefully fixed now.

Comment: Yes, this works now. However, it's still missing a closing bracket. Should be ```subprocess.check_call('echo "$RANDOM" >random-{}.txt'.format(i), shell=True)```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your edit suggestion, it got rejected before I got a chance to accept it.